# How to draw a single device pixel in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

It seems really simple:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

Unfortunately, in many devices this draws more than one pixel on the screen and sometimes a blurry blot. How can pixel-per-pixel control be achieved in an HTML5 `<canvas>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one CSS pixel is not defined as one pixel in the user's screen. In high PPI screens 1 CSS pixel ≠ 1 "real" pixel.

Fortunately, [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) contains the ratio between the length of 1 CSS pixel and 1 physical pixel. For example, a `devicePixelRatio` of 2 means that 1 CSS pixel = 2 physical pixels.

Here's a solution:

1. Create a canvas with the real size you want in physical pixels using the `width` and `height` attributes.
2. Using CSS, set the canvas size to the real size divided by `devicePixelRatio` in CSS pixels (for both dimensions) using the `width` and `height` CSS properties.
3. Draw to the canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.style.width = 200/devicePixelRatio + "px";
canvas.style.height = 100/devicePixelRatio + "px";

ctx.fillRect(2, 2, 1, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```